# Can I play an mpeg2 encoded .mpg file with javafx2 media

Tags: javafx-2, media, mpeg

I am working on a playout and wants to preview a .mpg file with javafx media .I have tried playing the file but MEDIA_UNSUPPORTED : Unrecognized file signature! exception was thrown
is it possible to do that using codecs if yes which codecs do i need to install .i havent tried anything else yet but suggestions are most welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, JavaFX 2 cannot play mpeg2 encoded files (with the exception of the audio layer [mp3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3)).

The list of [supported codec types](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html) for JavaFX is not extensible beyond those documented.

---

There is some [sample code](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2434712) to integrate the 3rd party [vlcj](http://code.google.com/p/vlcj/) component with a JavaFX 2 [canvas](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/canvas/Canvas.html) node, but that does not make use of JavaFX 2 [media](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/Media.html).

Comment: I tried to play video through vlcj's sample code for javafx but when the video gets played for sometime i am getting out of heap space error...I know i can increase the heap size but the video size can be larger than the maximum allowed heap for my computer.... i using direct media player component class for playing the video.... what should i do?

Comment: You can use tools such as [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) or the [NetBeans Profiler](http://profiler.netbeans.org) to track down memory leaks in your program.